# Knockout js getting page(s) unresponsive error while using continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, browser-cache

I'm using KnockOut js in Chat functionality.
In the left panel, Users will be displayed and on clicking the user, Chat conversation will be displayed in the Right Panel.
Now, My Problem is after few clicks, the browser is getting **over loaded** and popping out the page unresponsive error.

Is there anything like **Clear Cache**(Garbage Collection) kind of thing for browser?

I've tried **aborting** the old request, if any new request was made by using this code.

```
 if (xhr != null) {
            xhr.abort();
            xhr = null;
        }
```

Is there anything I can do with **Threading** in Javascript?

Comment: `page unresponsive` i.e stop script etc happens mostly when you try to send other request without completing initial request and also refrain using `async:false` in ajax calls & set `cache:false` . cheers

Comment: As JavaScript is single threaded, a lot of sync processing will hang up the event queue if you try `async:false` .

Comment: actually now we are clicking next user after everything got loaded only.
So, its almost equal to `async:false`.
But even then we are facing the same issue.

Comment: we've kept a loading panel to block user from clicking any other operation.

Comment: have you tried setting `cache:false` . a sample repro in fiddle will be quite useful .

Comment: even that didn't solve the issue :(

Comment: well i suppose i dished out all possible options for the cause . further hard  to say issue without actually seeing . Tip: open network tab & check http request time etc and normalize your code .

Comment: Could also be a runaway loop.

Comment: @satya check this techniques  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/ and try to find out .